# How to drop a resource use active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Any idea about to drop a resource which was created via active_admin gem in Rails 3.1.1?

Answer (score 2):

You can just delete or comment out the resource in the app/admin directory. It works for me (activeadmin 0.3.2).